# If null then insert in table_1 else return table_2 in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I am trying to insert using `if` statement in Sql server, but still confused on it.

```
SELECT A.id, B.id 
FROM table_a A 
LEFT JOIN table_b B ON A.id_a = B.id_b
```

It will be like this

```
    a.id         b.id
   --------------------
    1            1
    2            null
```

How to insert from `table_a` with not null on `table_b` (`a.id = 1`) to `table_insert_1` and if `null` (`a.id = 2`) insert from `table_a` to `table_insert_2` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this as :

```
INSERT INTO table_insert_1 (COL1,  . . . )
     SELECT A.Col1, . . .
     FROM table_a A
     WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_b B WHERE B.id_b = A.id_a);

 INSERT INTO table_insert_2 (COL1,  . . . )
     SELECT A.Col1, . . .
     FROM table_a A
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_b B WHERE B.id_b = A.id_a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two slightly different `INSERT` commands for that :

```
INSERT INTO table_insert_1
SELECT A.id, B.id 
FROM table_a A 
INNER JOIN table_b B ON A.id_a = B.id_b
WHERE A.id = 1;

INSERT INTO table_insert_2
SELECT A.id, B.id 
FROM table_a A 
LEFT JOIN table_b B ON A.id_a = B.id_b
WHERE B.id IS NULL A.id = 1;
```

The first `UPDATE` uses an `INNER JOIN` to select only records that can be found in the second table. The second uses a `LEFT JOIN` (optional), with a `WHERE` clause that filters out matching records.

Comment: They look like `insert`s to me.

Comment: @DamienTheUnbeliever : thanks for spotting the typo, fixed !

Comment: So I can't do that with just one query?

Comment: @TsabitAAziz : because you need to insert into two different tables, so you need two statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can write `if else` case by this given below.

```
IF ISNULL(@Id, 0)
BEGIN
"your sql statement"
END
else
BEGIN
"your sql statement"
END
```